# Getting the last character in a string

Tags: angular

I have a string value, e.g. `5d` and need to get the last character `d`. The string could be `5d` or `2d` or just `e`, etc.

I tried the following but get `5`:

```js
const timeLeft = this.myData[contentIndex].timeLeft;
const lastChar = timeLeft.substring(0, timeLeft.length - 1);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method along with [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property

```js
var str = '5d';
console.log(str.slice(str.length - 1))

var str = '3d';
console.log(str.slice(str.length - 1))

var str = 'e';
console.log(str.slice(str.length - 1))
```

Comment: `slice()` returns character on a zero-based index. So if the string is 'e' then `slice(str.length - 1)` would be `slice(0)` which would be `e`. So yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow code. very simple in js.

```
const timeLeft = this.myData[contentIndex].timeLeft;
const lastChar = timeLeft[timeLeft.length - 1];
```